# I need a way to pass unique object id in my django function based list view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have been stucked on this for a couple of days, all help would be really cherished.

I have a list and detail view which are function based views, my detail view works perfectly because i am able to pass the "/str:pk/" at the end of the url and also with the request as(def po_detail(request, pk)) which in turn i am able to pass into my view functions and they all successfully return the unique id i desire.

I have a custom queryset i have written to help me get the sum total amount of some payments and return it in both the list and detail view.

The issues now is that i am not able to get each unique items in my list view page because i am not able to pass the pk into the url and the request function as the object i used it for in detail function has access to the pk.

I have id=True so as to prevent error, because when i made id=id, it gave me a error saying, "Field 'id' expected a number but got ."

[The image is pictorial representation of the list template which output both the payment amount and the balance of only the first id instead of the individual id as opposed in the detail template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXJFo.png).

[This is the image of the detail template which works well as well as for other id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijENH.png)

I would love if any one can provide an hint, suggestion, or solution.

Thanks,
Oyero H.O

Below is my model

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):

created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
po_type = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrderType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=15)
supplier_ID = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
order_date = models.DateField()
desired_ship_date = models.DateField()
ready_date = models.DateField()
po_amount = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.id)

class PurchaseOrderPayment(models.Model):
po_number = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
date = models.DateField()
amount = models.IntegerField()
memo = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.memo
```

Below is my view function

```
@login_required(redirect_field_name='po_list')
def po_list(request):
po_lists = PurchaseOrder.objects.all()
po_detail = PurchaseOrder.objects.get(id=True)
payment_lists_doc = PurchaseOrderPayment.objects.filter(po_number__id=True)
amount = po_detail.po_amount
paid_amount = PurchaseOrderPayment.objects.filter(po_number=po_detail).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']
balance = amount - paid_amount  

context = {'po_lists':po_lists, 'payment_lists_doc':payment_lists_doc,
'amount':amount, 'paid_amount':paid_amount, 'balance':balance,
'payment_lists_doc':payment_lists_doc
}
return render(request, 'dashboard/po_list.html', context)

@login_required(redirect_field_name='po_detail')
def po_detail(request, pk):
po_detail = PurchaseOrder.objects.get(id=pk)
payment_lists_doc = PurchaseOrderPayment.objects.filter(po_number__id=pk)
document_lists_doc = PurchaseOrderDocument.objects.filter(po_number__id=pk)

amount = po_detail.po_amount
paid_amount = PurchaseOrderPayment.objects.filter(po_number=po_detail).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum']

balance = amount - paid_amount

context = {'po_detail':po_detail, 'payment_lists_doc':payment_lists_doc, 
'payment_form':payment_form, 'document_form':document_form, 
'document_lists_doc':document_lists_doc, 
'paid_amount':paid_amount,
'balance':balance, 'amount':amount}

return render(request, 'dashboard/po_detail.html', context)
```

This is my list template

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>CREATED</th>
                  <th>TYPE</th>
                  <th>STATUS</th>
                  <th>SUPPLIER NAME</th>
                  <th>ORDER DATE</th>
                  <th>AMOUNT</th>
                  <th>PAID AMOUNT</th>
                  <th>BALANCE AMOUNT</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {% for po_list in po_lists %}
                <tr>
                  <td style="cursor: pointer;"><a href="{% url 'po_detail' pk=po_list.pk %}">{{po_list.id}}</a></td>
                  <td>{{po_list.created_on}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_list.po_type}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_list.status}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_list.supplier_ID}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_list.order_date}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_list.po_amount}}</td>
                  <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paid_amount_modal" style="cursor: pointer;">
                  {{paid_amount}}
                  </td>
                  <td>{{balance}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

And lastly, my detail template

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>CREATED</th>
                  <th>TYPE</th>
                  <th>STATUS</th>
                  <th>SUPPLIER NAME</th>
                  <th>ORDER DATE</th>
                  <th>AMOUNT</th>
                  <th>PAID AMOUNT</th>
                  <th>BALANCE AMOUNT</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><a href="{% url 'po_edit' pk=po_detail.pk %}">{{po_detail.id}}</a></td>
                  <td>{{po_detail.created_on}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_detail.po_type}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_detail.status}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_detail.supplier_ID}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_detail.order_date}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_detail.po_amount}}</td>
                  <td>{{paid_amount}}</td>
                  <td>{{balance}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
              <div></div>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it,

screenshot included,
mark my answer if that helped.

Edit your models.py

```
    class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
...

    @property
    def get_payments_sum(self):
        return sum(item.get_amount for item in self.items.all())
    
    @property
    def get_balance(self):
        return  self.get_payments_sum - self.po_amount

class PurchaseOrderPayment(models.Model):
    po_number = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="items")

    ...

    @property
    def get_amount(self):
        return self.amount
```

views.py

note that i only edited as to fix your issue (sum and balance), so you have to add whatever else remaining in context like "payment_lists_doc"

```
def po_list(request):
po_lists = PurchaseOrder.objects.all()
context = {'po_lists':po_lists}
return render(request, 'dashboard/po_list.html', context)
```

po_lists.html

```
                  <tbody>
                {% for po_list in po_lists %}
                <tr>
                  <td style="cursor: pointer;"><a href="{% url 'po_detail' pk=po_list.pk %}">{{po_list.id}}</a></td>
                  <td>{{po_list.created_on}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_list.po_type}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_list.status}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_list.order_date}}</td>
                  <td>{{po_list.po_amount}}</td>
                  <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#paid_amount_modal" style="cursor: pointer;">
                  {{po_list.get_payments_sum}}
                  </td>
                   <td>{{po_list.get_balance}}</td> 
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDLh4.png)

Comment: Thanks do much yousef

Your solution worked perfectly, i just got the trick.

Comment: Thanks @yousef, until now i am just able to upvote an answer and mark it as the accepted answer which i have righfully done on your answer as it provides an amazing solution to my need.
Thanks and have a great day

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your error

po_detail = PurchaseOrder.objects.get(id=True)
payment_lists_doc =

PurchaseOrderPayment.objects.filter(po_number__id=True)
amount = po_detail.po_amount = True

You need to pass an id (integer) to these fields

Comment: Sure sir, i have tried that but i get id is a built-in function

If you look closely, you will observe that the same kind of logic has been used in po_detail view but since it has pk passed in the url and along the request in the view, i am able to use it 

How then can i pass pk in the po_list which is is list view and get same ressult